# nmake, visualstudio, and .mak files

Tags: visual-studio, nmake

I was given a C++ project that was compiled using MS Visual Studio .net 2003 C++ compiler, and a .mak file that was used to compile it.  I am able to build it from the command line using nmake project.mak, but the compiler complains that afxres.h was not found.  I did a little searching around and the afxres.h is in the Visual Studio directory in an includes file.  Where am I supposed to specify to nmake where to look for this header file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be an icon in your Start menu under Programs that opens a cmd.exe instance with all the correct MSVS environment variables set up for command line building.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is running the appropriate `vars` batch file from a regular command prompt.  The name and location varies from version to version.  For VS2003, I believe it's

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat`

Comment: @Daniel: I like your  `"(yes, there are still people using VS2K3. don't ask.)"`.